# An Expression for $\Delta T$ for a Thermal Conductivity derivation

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

In kinetic theory, the thermal conductivity of a gas is $$K = \frac{1}{3} C vl.$$ In deriving this formula, why is the following equation valid?

"Now $ \Delta T$ between the ends of a free path of the particle is given by
$$ \Delta T = \frac{dT}{dx}l_x $$ 
where $\tau$ is the average time between collisions."

This is found in Kittel, chapter 5.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that there is a uniform temperature gradient $\text{d}T/\text{d}x$ along some path of length $l_x$ then the temperature difference between the two ends of the path is $\text{d}T/\text{d}x \cdot l_x$.